# Rails try() method with where constraint in active query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following models:

Supplier has many submitted_prices

Submitted_prices have many price_items

In order for the code not to crash when there are no submitted_prices and/or no price_items, I used to use the following:

```
 if supplier.submitted_prices.where(:purchaser_id => organization.id).last
 && supplier.submitted_prices.where(:purchaser_id => organization.id).last.price_items.where("item_id" => item.id).last
 && supplier.submitted_prices.where(:purchaser_id => organization.id).last.price_items.where("item_id" => item.id).last.unit_price.present?
  order_item.unit_price = supplier.submitted_prices.where(:purchaser_id => organization.id).last.price_items.where("item_id" => item.id).last.unit_price
```

Then I came across try():

```
order_item.unit_price = supplier.try(:submitted_prices).where(:purchaser_id => organization.id).try(:last).try(:price_items).where("item_id" => item.id).try(:last).try(:unit_price)
```

Problem is, I don't know how to run try() on the WHERE constraints and this constraints fails if try returns nil:

```
NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `where' for nil:NilClass
```

Is there a way to wrap try() around the WHERE constraint?

Comment: You have way too much going on in that `if` statement, and lots of law of demeter issues. The condition’s parts should be extracted into separate, meaningful, semantic methods.

Comment: Thanks, I started to refactor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done without `try`, and in a more logical, understandable format.

```
submitted_price = supplier.submitted_prices.where(purchaser_id: organization.id).order("created_at desc").first
price_item      = submitted_price.price_items.where(item_id: item.id).order("created_at desc").first if submitted_price.present?

order_item.unit_price = price_item.unit_price if price_item.present?
```

This assumes a default ordering of your model by their `:created` attribute.

Answer (score 7):

First, don't use `try`, IMHO, it is a code smell.

If you still want to, then you need to use it in every call after the first try.

```
supplier.try(:submitted_prices).try(:where, {purchaser_id: organization.id}).try(:last).try(:price_items).try(:where, {item_id: item.id}).try(:last).try(:unit_price)
```

This surely shows some bad design. Try to refactor it first!

Comment: Thanks, I started to refactor

Answer (score 4):

[`try`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try) accepts arguments as its subsequent parameters, for example:

```
try(:where, :purchaser_id => organization.id)
```

I would advise you to extract a lot of this logic out into separate scopes and methods, there is far too much happening in that one `if` statement, and it’s reaching far too deep into your object graph. You may wish to read about the [Law of Demeter/Principle of Least Knowledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).

Comment: Thanks, I started to refactor

Comment: @MichaelImstepf If this answer was helpful don't forget to [upvote it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130046/158402) `:)`

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could get rid of such complexities by reading the documentation.
(also, it would be great if you broke that chain of boolean clauses in different lines. I'm really finding hard to understand what you are trying to do there)

You should probably check out the methods `association.empty?` and `association.exists?(conditions)`. [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_many-association-reference)